# What is the state of the art for rough path regularity on coefficients?

Tags: differential-equations, stochastic-differential-equations, rough-paths

Consider the rough differential equation

$$dY_t=b(Y_t,t) \, dt+\sigma(Y_t,t) \, d\mathbf X_t,$$

where $\mathbf X$ is a $p$-rough path with $1\leq p<3$. If $b$ and $\sigma$ are $C^3_b$ then we have existence, uniqueness, stability, etc. I know $b$ can be reduced to just Lipschitz. What about further? What if $b$ is discontinuous, merely continuous, etc.?